# How to limit number of connections per username in openvpn server?

Tags: openvpn

I have an openvpn server and I setup a username & password auth

I gave my customers 1 username and password plus a .ovpn file

I want to limit max connections per usernames of my each customers:

e.g.

- Customer1: password1 -> max connections = 2
- Customer2: password2 -> max connections = 1

...

Comment: You can find the solution from https://serverfault.com/questions/850599/permit-only-n-connection-for-a-user-config-in-openvpn/850889